# NVIM - convert buffer number into buffer

Tags: lua, neovim

At some point I saw a function that would allow you to get the buffer from the buffer number.

I cannot find that function anymore. I searched the documentation for bufnr buffer etc. but I couldn't find it anymore.

Basically I am trying to do something like :

```lua
function (client, bufnr) 
  local buffer = nvim_get_buffer(bufnr)
  buffer.lsp.formatting()
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `vim.lsp.buf.format` function with  buffer number, see [Neovim LSP docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lsp.html) :

```
function (client, bufnr) 
  vim.lsp.buf.format({ bufnr = bufnr })
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this handy callback thingy, but sadly not the thing that I wanted. Luckily this is good enough to solve my usecase, hope this helps someone.

```lua
vim.api.nvim_buf_call(bufnr, function()
  vim.lsp.buf.formatting_sync()
end)
```